# Antd ImgCrop when minZoom below 1 always get cropped like zoom 1

Tags: reactjs, image, antd

I am using antd imgCrop for cropping image. I want to make the image not cropped when zoom below 1.

The example is below:

When i zoom out like that i want the image have a white space like the screenshot with red border.
[image]

original image
[image]
but the result my image get cropped
[image]

is there a way so my image not getting cropped when zoom below 1? so the output is image with whitespace.
https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-img-crop-forked-x8j16z?file=/src/index.js

Thank you before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution by Adding Cropperprops and set restric position to false

```
<ImgCrop
   cropperProps={{ restrictPosition: false }}
>
```